# referencing the drop-down box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have this code to verify that.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- alert("Testing"); --> </script>
```

This code now makes a popup box on form page. All working as expected! Now the problem I'm having is referencing the drop-down box. I thought the following code should have done the trick but no.

```
var element; var i=EG;
element=document.getElementById("client_country"); element.selectedIndex = i;
```

But I cant seem to get it to work. I think its due to the use of frames, anyone able to point me in the direction of where I’m going wrong?

Comment: post a portion of your html with the drop down

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 'EG'; // string inside quotes
var element = document.getElementById("client_country");
element.value = i; // set the selected option

// selectedIndex retrieves the value
var selected_value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

This assumes you have HTML similar to...

```
<select id="client_country">
    <option value="AG">value a</option>
    <option value="CG">value c</option>
    <option value="EG">value e</option>
</select>
```

Working demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgrfsh/fwyQV/).

Comment: just nothing new happen the form display normal with the first selected country is 'United States'

Comment: See my edit... Your `select` must have the right `id`, and the JavaScript is referencing the `option` `value`s... **not** the option text. I tested this in Chrome and it works.

Comment: See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgrfsh/fwyQV/)... I select the first `option` in the HTML, but the JS changes it to the last `option`. If you comment out the call to `changeValue()`, it no longer changes the selected value.

Comment: thanks lan this JSFiddle is nice but still not working; My form Html is loaded from another server in an iframe, does this make any change?

Comment: That changes everything. I suspect you're attempting cross-site scripting, which will prevent any change. If the iframe was on the same server you would reference the iframe by `id`.